# What is the common chinese phrase for the "Home" section of a website / app?

Tags: internet-slang, websites

For example you go to any popular website / app, there will be a "Home" section. What is the chinese phrase? for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually it would be called 首页. Sometime 主页.